# Can I embed google map with three markers for free

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary

I'm creating a website, and I need to insert google map with three markers, can I make this for free, or I need to use Google API Key.

```
        function initMap() {
          // The location of Uluru
          var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
          var uluru1 = {lat: -20.344, lng: 120.036};
          var uluru2 = {lat: -20.344, lng: 125.036};
          // The map, centered at Uluru
          var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
          // The marker, positioned at Uluru
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
          var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru1, map: map});
          var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru2, map: map});
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the pricing depends on the map loadings, not on the markers. See here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

Comment: but it works for 1 sec and then give an error: Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details. inside the console: Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how much Pins you show or whatever, it's just about how much your map is loaded. It's also not possible to use google maps without a credit card added to the api key. So if you go over the free limit google will charge you automatically.

If you don't like this you should have a look at other map services.